# Angular using disable form control typed forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm updating all my angular forms to typed forms. I define it like follows:

```
readonly personForm: FormGroup<{
    name: FormControl<string>
    favorites: FormControl<string[] | null>
}>;
```

And I initialize it like:

```
this.personForm = this.fb.group({
    name: this.fb.nonNullable.control("", Validators.required),
    favorites: new FormControl({ value: [""], disabled: false})
});
```

Somewhere in the code I'm resetting the form once I get the data from the API. The "favorites" is a select from a list from another API method, let's call it `food`.
If this `food` list is empty, then

```
this.personForm.reset({
    name: person.name,
    favorites: {
        value: person.favorites || [],
        disabled: this.food && this.food.length < 1
    }
});
```

Where `person` is the constant which contains my API data response.

On this `favorites` assignation I get a TS error:
[image]

So I'm guessing the way I'm defining the `FormControl` it's not correct at all. How do I have to define it?

Comment: Well, it seems like you try to assign an object with attributes `value` and `disabled` to your form control value of type `string[]`. Maybe you wanted to assign this `value` attribute to your form control (using `setValue`) and your `disabled` attribute to the form accordingly.

Comment: But with the UntypedFormGroup I have no problems. How should the definition be then?

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you try to assign the value to your formControl? Best would be a StackBlitz example containing all provided code.

Comment: Usually, by the Angular documentation, you create FormControl or FormGroup instances only once in the constructor or ngOnInit, unless form is dynamic by design (form fields will be added or removed in runtime). If just value of the form should be changed there is methods reset(), setValue() and patchValue().

Comment: But I'm reseting the whole form once I get the data loaded, on the `ngOnInit`. Let me update the code  a bit. I have more fields, not just 2. But the only problem I get is with the disabled.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note :

- If you use the form builder, you only need it on `group`
- If you have a required validator, you don't need the `nonNullable` option

Your code can then become :

```js
this.personForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    favorites: ''
});
```

Then, if you implement the solution, you can make it more concise too :

```js
this.personForm.patchValue({
    name: person.name,
    favorites: person.favorites ?? []
});
if (!this.food?.length) this.personForm.get('favorites').disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch your control value with it's type:

```
  favorites: person.favorites || []
```

And then check if it should be disabled:

```
const favoritesControl = this.personForm.controls.favorites;

if (this.food && this.food.length < 1 && favoritesControl.enabled) {
  favoritesControl.disable();
}
```

P.s. your code works with `UntypedFormControl` because of wrong value assigned. In your reset function:

```
favorites: {
        value: person.favorites || [],
        disabled: this.food && this.food.length < 1
    }
```

assigns object value with props. And actually it will not be disabled even if the same prop `disabled` is true. And now your control have not a string array value, but object.

Comment: So with your proposal it works, but I don't really understand how it used to work without being typed and now it doesn't eventhough disabled & value are props of a FormControl. That's why I think there's something wrong in the FormControl definition.